# windows phone "On Unlock Phone Event"

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I thinking about simple app for wp runtime 8.1. it's something like custom key after unlock phone. It's any passible to acces of this state, event etc?

thx, for help 
T.

Comment: There is no global event for the phone being unlocked.

Comment: that's mean developer don't have acces for this event?

Comment: Correct; you can suggest the feature at [UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com)